# Curvilinear plots with sjplot

Tags: r, plot, mixed-models, quadratic, sjplot

I have a mixed model (using nlme) with time and time quadratic (time2). How can I let sjp.int (of sjplot) ask to plot it curvilinear?

```
   model = lme(MR ~ Age* time + sex*time + ed* time+ time* HMD+time2*HMD, random=~1|subject, na.action="na.omit",data=mydata);summary(model)
```

I called sjplot as:

```
  sjp.int(model, type="eff", swap.pred=T, mdrt.values="quart", show.ci=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quadratic term should have the same name, i.e. you should be using `poly()` or `I()^2`. See following example:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
fit <- lm(tot_sc_e ~ c161sex * e17age + c161sex * I(e17age^2), data = efc)
sjp.int(fit)
```

[image]

Note that the order of the predictors for the interaction terms are important and should be the same in the formula (i.e. in the above case, `c161sex` comes first, then `e17age`).

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the help, this was indeed the trick! 
Just an additional question, is there a way to plot three-way interactions (e.g. HMD * time * group) and then have a plot where the effect HMD*time is split across my two groups? I tried with facet.grid=TRUE, but it is giving me weird plots (I tried to convert the factor into numeric, but that didn't help)

Comment: Three-way-interaction is not implemented yet, see https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/issues/103. still needs some conceptional thinking